# or-tools, CP SAT: usage of target of AddDivisionEquality in a goal function

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

Dears,
is it possible to use the target value of AddDivisionEquality of CP SAT (or-tools) as variable to be maximized in a goal function?

Answer (score 0):

of course. Any linear combination of variables is a valid objective function.

Comment: Thank you, I'm asking this for the following reason: Assume that x is the target variable of a AddDivisionEquality (X, numerator, denominator). where numerator is an expression and denominator is a constant. If I maximize X I get different results if I maximize numerator expression. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I do not get it, AddDivisionEquality only accept integer variables or integer constant as arguments. Expressions are not supposed to be valid. What expression do you pass ?

Comment: In the constraitns I'm creating a constraint like int_var=expression, then I'm using the int_var as numerator of the division, while the denominator is a constant. If I maximize the division target variable I get a result that is different from when I maximize directly the expression I used in the int_var. I hope this clarify

Comment: x [0..10], if you maximize x / 3, you get x = 9 or 10, if you maximize x, you always get 10